# Are eigenvalues of slashed covariant derivative real?

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-theory, differentiation, dirac-equation

I am trying to demonstrate that the slashed covariant derivative
$$
\gamma^\mu D_\mu = \gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu -iA_\mu)
$$
has real eigenvalues:
$$ 
\gamma^\mu D_\mu \varphi_m(x)=\lambda_m \varphi_m(x) \Rightarrow \lambda_m \in \mathbb{R}
$$
However I do not know how to prove this.

I am a bit confused and I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Why do you think it should be Hermitian? Also, Hermitian on what vector space?

Comment: In the lecture notes of an subject that I am studying it is said that is hermitian so its eigenvalues are real, and this is used to proof some properties of anomalies. Thank you!

Comment: Specify the underying space (of functions) and the associated scalar product. Otherwise your question does not make sense.

Comment: 1. The Dirac operator in Lorentzian signature is not (on the most natural space to consider it on) Hermitian, see also [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/763652/50583). 2. QFT does not have a scalar product *on the space of fields* - the fields are operators, not states, and the scalar product of quantum theories is on the space of states, so it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: 3. Your first displayed equation makes no sense since it has mismatched indices - on the l.h.s. is the Dirac operator with no free indices, but on the r.h.s. is the covariant derivative with a free $\mu$

Comment: @ACuriousMind That is my concern also.

Comment: I have edited the question to bind the index on the r.h.s. of the first equation. I think my edit is what OP was trying to write...